# Can a Wicket form component be dynamically changed if it's set to "required"?

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

EDIT:
This question was originally about checkboxes, but I am getting the same behavior with a dropdown list. The code:

```
productInput = new DropDownChoice<String>("productInput",
                                          new PropertyModel<String>(this, "productSelection"),
                                          products);

productInput.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
        if (productSelection == null) // Breakpoint is set on this line
        {
            updateDropdownsAfterFieldDisabled(1, target);
        }
        else
        {
            updateDropdownsAfterFieldEnabled(1, target);
        }
    }
});
```

If `productInput` is not set to required, the breakpoint gets hit every time the list goes from having some value selected to having the blank line option selected. If it is set to required, the breakpoint never gets hit.

---

Is it possible to dynamically/AJAX-ishly change a Wicket form component if it's being validated with `setRequired(true);`? Here's a simple, if contrived, example to show what I mean:

Drive-through carwashes at gas stations usually often three or four levels of service. Each one includes everything provided by the lower levels and tacks on one more coat of wax or an extra rinse or something. UIs for the washes usually have four buttons with lights next to them ([example](http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/50274/50274,1142370444,2/stock-photo-payment-for-automatic-car-wash-1084570.jpg)). When a user presses one of the buttons, the corresponding light turns on, along with all the lights of the cheaper levels; the lights for nicer levels turn off. That behavior is modeled by this code:

```
boolean economy, standard, deluxe, ultimate = false;

CheckBox economyBox = new CheckBox("economyBox",
                                   new PropertyModel<Boolean>(this, "economy"));
// Similar declarations for standardBox, deluxeBox and ultimatebox

OnChangeAjaxBehavior standardChangeListener = new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
        // If "standard" is activated, also turn on the "economy" light
        if (standard)
        {
            economy = true;
            target.addComponent(economyBox);
        }
        // If "standard" is deactivated, deactivate "deluxe" and "ultimate"
        else if (!standard)
        {
            deluxe = false;
            ultimate = false;
            target.addComponent(deluxeBox);
            target.addComponent(ultimateBox);
        }
    }
};
standardBox.add(standardChangeListener);
// Similar listeners declared for the other three checkboxes
```

I've tested this code — well, the real code that this is a simplified version of — and it works as expected. But add in `economyBox.setRequired(true);` and the box stops updating dynamically. Is there a way to add validation without breaking the "linked checkbox" behavior?

Comment: In what way does it stop working?

Comment: @Don it ceases to be affected by the state of the other checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong here except you have

```
        target.addComponent(standardBox);
```

where I think you intended

```
        target.addComponent(economyBox);
```

Validation should interoperate with `OnChangeAjaxBehavior` just fine.  I'm quite sure I've used both in some forms, though not I think with checkboxes.

I'm not sure the idea of validation with `economyBox.setRequired(true);` makes sense here though.  You're supplying values, defaulting to false for all the checkboxes, in your model, so there's no real way for anything to be actually omitted in this context.

A more sensible validation might be that **something** has to be checked, but that would require a different validator defined for the form as a whole, or for a `FormComponent` incorporating all your checkboxes.

**EDIT:**
Based on your edit about seeing the same issue with `DropDownChoice`, I did an experiment.

There is an example of `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` with `DropDownChoice` components [here](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/ajax/choice).  I downloaded the code for this, added

```
    models.setRequired(true);
    makes.setRequired(true);
    add(new FeedbackPanel("messages"));
```

and of course added markup for the feedback panel.

It validated the required fields and continued to update the model drop-down based on the value of the make dropdown.

Since this worked fine for me, I'd recommend you try the same, see it work and then compare with your code.

Comment: You're right about the typo. I was smart enough to create that sample with Eclipse's refactor tool, but then I went and ruined it by copy/pasting in an attempt to shorten the post. It's fixed now.

Comment: Typo aside, I have found that the validator doesn't accept `false` for a checkbox with `setRequired(true)`. Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental about how `PropertyModel` works/ties things together? I actually agree that a better validator would be "make sure __something__ is checked," but I couldn't figure out how to make that work either, and I thought I'd start with an easier question.

Comment: There's example code at https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/validating-related-fields.html that might be helpful in understanding how to do the validation.

Comment: Yeah, I've already played around with `AbstractValidator` some; thought I was getting ahead of myself.

Comment: Your edit is funny, in a sad way, because that's the code I started with. I'll take another look at it. I guess I'll accept this for now, congrats on Unsung Hero (in a week).